# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when class not found

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have the below code that successfully scrapes the business categories from [https://www.canpages.ca/business/AB/edmonton/restaurants/183-720200-p41.html"](https://www.canpages.ca/business/AB/edmonton/restaurants/183-720200-p41.html%22), however on page 42 there is a company that has no category (the class is "result__business-category" under the "result-id" class).

This particular company shows as not actually having the class in the html, while the other results do.  I'm not sure the best way to approach this, as my program crashes once it sees the class does not exist.
the error is "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" and the code is as follows:

```
import re #regex
import requests #fetches html page content
from requests import get 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #parses html page content
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#initialize empty list where we can store data
categories = []

#Get the contents of the page we're looking at by requesting the URL
results = requests.get("https://www.canpages.ca/business/AB/edmonton/restaurants/183-720200-p42.html", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(results.text, "html.parser")

#grab the container of each company by result id
companies_div = soup.find_all('div', {'id': re.compile('result-id-.*')})

for x in companies_div:

    # Extract category class and split by white space.  Category should follow [City Category] but sometimes typos result in [Category]
    categoryChunk = x.find('div', class_='result__business-category').text.split()

    # if list does not have [City Category] format and therefore list length of 2, mark as "-"
    category = categoryChunk[1] if len(categoryChunk) == 2 else '-'
    categories.append(category)

#ininitalize pd dataframe
companies = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': categories,
    })

print(companies)

companies.to_csv('companiestest6.csv')
```

I'm not sure how I can basically tell the program "if it can't find the class, mark the category as "-" and would really appreciate any help.

**Update**

I have updated the code as follows:

```
categoryDiv = x.find('div', class_='result__business-category')

        if categoryDiv:
            categoryChunk = categoryDiv.text.split()
            if len(addressChunk) == 3:
                category = categoryChunk[1]
                categories.append(category)

            else:
                category = '-'
                categories.append(category)

        else:
            category = '-'
            categories.append(category)
```

Which seems to work perfectly!

Comment: After `results = requests.get(...)`, you just need `if not results:` and then do whatever you need to do with a null result.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I updated the code at the bottom of my post with a similar solution which solved the problem, but now I need to somehow check that the length of my list = 2 in order to assign it to the variable (which originally worked before incorporating this solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should be able to fairly simply test for what is returned by the `.find`.

```py
div = x.find('div', class_='result__business-category')

if div:
    categoryChunk = div.text.split()

    category = categoryChunk[1]

else:
    category = '-'
```

This won't explicitly test for the length being 2, but I'm assuming that was just to try to get if it wasn't found.